# Need to check if 7 specific tags exist on a list of azure VMs

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

Hello I need to check for if a list of azure VMs have 7 specific tags using PowerShell, the tag values don't need to be checked. If any of the 7 tags are missing then the script will need to write error and print what tags were missing. I can get the tags from

```
$vmDetails = Get-AzVM -Name $sourceVMName -ResourceGroupName $sourceResourceGroupName
$vmTags = $vmDetails.Tags
```

Then I can run a loop

```
foreach ($keyval in $vmtags.keys)
```

but I am unsure how to do the comparison without a bunch of if statements. I'm sure an array is needed but can't remember what may be best. thanks a bunch.

Comment: Are you sure the `Tag` property is a hashtable? From what I can see on MS Docs: `Tags: {"creationSource":"acs-VirtualMachine07"}` doesn't seem to be an actual hashtable and requires some manipulation.

Comment: What's wrong with several `if()` conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Tags` property is a `hashtable` as you have shown on your code, the code (pseudo code as I don't have a way of testing this) could look like this:

```
# Get the base Tags needed to compare
$vmDetails = Get-AzVM -Name $sourceVMName -ResourceGroupName $sourceResourceGroupName

# Assuming the Tags property is a Hashtable
$vmTags = $vmDetails.Tags.Keys

# Get the count of Tags
$i = $vmTags.Count

# Get all existing VMs on a Resource Group
$allVMs = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $sourceResourceGroupName

foreach($vm in $allVMs)
{
    # Store the Tags of this VM
    $thisVMtags = $vm.Tags.Keys

    # If the count of Tags of this VMs is not the same as the count of Base Tags
    if($thisVMtags.Count -ne $i)
    {
        # Get the missing Tags of this VM
        $missingTags = $vmTags.where({
            $_ -notin $thisVMtags
        }) -join ', '

        # Write a warning with details of this VM Name and the missing Tags
        Write-Warning "{0} is missing the following Tags: {1}" -f $vm.Name, $missingTags
    }
}
```